# Textarea and Input vs Textbox

Tags: html

I noticed on a few places (mainly Youtube's comments), there are "textbox" instead of the normal "textarea".

`<div role="textbox" aria-multiline="true"></div>` vs `<textarea></textarea>`

Also I see `<div role="textbox"></div>` instead of `<input type="text">`

Is there any functionality advantages to use `role="textbox"` instead of `textarea` or `input`?  Or is this just pure preference? For example, is it easier to modify or edit using Javascript?

[image: YT comments1]

As you see above, I am selecting the comment box with Chrome's inspector.

[image: YT comments2]

Now I added text to the comment box, and the text appears inside the div element stated above when viewing Chrome's inspector.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_textbox_role

Comment: @j08691 I have read through that, and all I could get is that some accessibility features (probably mainly on Mac) work better with this, but I'm looking more for functionality advantages.  For example, is it easier to modify using Javascript? Sorry not being clear, I am updating my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are seeing that a div should be a textbox, but that's incorrect. The tag is input, not div.

But, to your larger question the role attribute pertains to the WAI-ARIA standard, which relates to user accessibility for those who use assistive technologies, such as screen readers. It allows those users to navigate a page more easily because the screen reader has a better idea of what elements are what on the page.

There are no new functions that the text field takes on because of the use of this attribute. ARIA is about accessibility.

You can read a bit more about this, particularly relating to text fields at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_textbox_role

Comment: For your first sentence, I was referencing the YT comments.  The code for the textbox (after you click on it) is `<div class="comment-simplebox-text" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" contenteditable="plaintext-only"></div>`.

Comment: YouTube comments?  I don't know what you were looking at, but textboxes are not produced with div elements. You need input or textarea.

Comment: I will edit my question to show screenshots of what I see

Comment: It's not going to change the answer about what the role attribute is or why using it with the value of textbox is useful.

Comment: But you seem to not believe me when I said it was a div.  So just to show that the div is creating the textbox, I am including screenshots.  But so far you guys are basically saying that there is no advantage, just as I thought.

Comment: I do believe you, but You Tube's page is much more complex. They are using the contenteditible attribute so that a user can come back and edit comments after they've already submitted one. This is not the same thing as a textbox, but You Tube is using the role=textbox for assistive technologies to be able to find those elements. Again, this is not a textbox, nor does it add any new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this while looking into the same. The accepted answer is just flat out wrong.

Take a look at for example LinkedIn messaging or Gmail email body writer. This looks like it's a pretty common feature of web based rich-text editors. I'm not sure exactly how they go about this but my guess is to listen to keyboard inputs and use that to generate text based on internal state of the editor.

You simply can't have all that the features such as styling, font-size and inline images with the standard `textarea` or `<input type="text">` fields unless you provide a split view (think markdown editors).